# Elements appended to array return nil

Tags: swift

I have an array of UIImages I want split into two separate arrays,
one containing objects whose index is even, and the other with objects whose index is odd.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var evenImages: [UIImage]?
var oddImages: [UIImage]?

var imageArray: [UIImage]? {
    didSet{

        for z in 0..<((imageArray?.count)!) {
            if z % 2 == 0 {
                evenImages?.append(imageArray![z])
            } else {
                oddImages?.append(imageArray![z])
            }

            print(evenImages?.count) //prints nil
            print(oddImages?.count) //prints nil
        }
    }
}
```

The issue so far is that while the objects are seemingly being appended to the appropriate arrays, whenever I try to use them they are nil. Perhaps this is an issue with the order in which the variables are instantiated? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
evenImages?.append(imageArray![z])
```

What this line means is: "If `evenImages` is not `nil`, append `imageArray![z]` to it."

Unfortunately, if `evenImages` is `nil`, nothing will happen. And since it appears you never initialized it, this is going to be the case.

Later on:

```
print(evenImages?.count)
```

This means: "if `evenImages` is not `nil`, then print its `count`. Otherwise, just print `nil`." Unfortunately, `evenImages` is still `nil`, so you get `nil`.

Solution: `evenImages` doesn't need to be optional at all. Just initialize it to an empty array straight off:

```
var evenImages: [UIImage] = []
var oddImages: [UIImage] = []
```

Then you can get rid of all the `?` marks when accessing it, and it'll never be `nil`.

Sidenote: I'd recommend also changing `imageArray` to be non-optional, and initializing it to an empty `[]` array as well. This way, you can get rid of the ugly (and crash-prone, if a `nil` happens to unexpectedly get in there somehow) `!` when you append its components to your even and odd arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You've forgot to initialise the arrays

Try adding

```
evenImages = []
oddImages = []
```

before your for loop